# Serverless AWS Lambda does not complete Flask thread

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda

I am developing a slash command on Slack and am Serverless Python Flask API to deploy the server on AWS Lambda.

Here is the code of the slash command:

```
@app.route('/api-route', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def foo():
    slack_web_client = WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_ORG_ADMIN_USER_TOKEN'])
    start = time()

    data = request.form
    user_id = data.get('user_id')
    text = data.get('text')
    response_url = data.get('response_url')

    @copy_current_request_context
    def foo_execute(user_id, text, response_url):
        print("######## foo_execute #########")

        print("###### Part 1 ########")
        params = text.split(" ")
        if len(params) != 1:
            print("######## Part 1 Error #########")
            requests.post(response_url, data=json.dumps({'text':':negative_squared_cross_mark: Error'}))
            return make_response("", 404)

        new_pass = params[0]

        print("######## Part 2 ########")
        if len(new_pass) < 12 or not re.search("[a-z]", new_pass) or not re.search("[A-Z]", new_pass) or not re.search("[0-9]", new_pass):
            print("######## Part 2 Error #########")
            requests.post(response_url, data=json.dumps({'text': ':negative_squared_cross_mark: Error'}))
            return make_response("", 404)

        print("######## Part 3 #########")
        user_email = None
        try:
            user_email = slack_web_client.users_info(user=user_id)['user']['profile']['email']

        except SlackApiError as e:
            print("######## Part 3 Error #########")
            requests.post(response_url, data=json.dumps({'text': ':negative_squared_cross_mark: Error'}))
            return make_response("", 404)
            
        print("###### Part 4 ######")
        try:
            # API call to get user from another service
        except:
            print("######## Part 4 Error #########")
            requests.post(response_url, data=json.dumps({'text': ':negative_squared_cross_mark: Error'}))
            return make_response("", 404)

        try:
            print("###### Part 5 ########")
            # change password in another service
            print("Execution time: " + str(time() - start))
            requests.post(response_url, data=json.dumps({'text': ':white_check_mark: foo_execute completed'}))
            return make_response("", 200)

        except Exception as e:
            print("######## Part 5 Error #########")
            requests.post(response_url, data=json.dumps({'text': ':negative_squared_cross_mark: Error'}))
            return make_response("", 404)

    process = Thread(target=foo_execute, args=[user_id, text, response_url])
    process.start()
    return ':hourglass_flowing_sand: Your request is being serviced...'
```

In the CloudWatch logs, the thread only logs from part 1 to 3 and does not reach part 6 of `foo_execute`. However, when I use repl.it project to serve the app, it completes the function. Why does the thread not complete in AWS Lambda?

Comment: While `...` is a valid Python expression, it isn't what really happens there, is it?

Comment: @KlausD. Yup, i wrote `...` instead to hide what the slash command does. But they are API calls

Comment: And how are we going to help you if you just show us `...` and prints? Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @KlausD. I've added more details